# Как отобразить окно с прогрессом распаковки 7z архива?

Tags: c#, 7z

У меня есть код, который распаковывает архив в нужную папку:

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = archiver;

            startInfo.Arguments = " x";

            startInfo.Arguments += " -y";

            startInfo.Arguments += " " + "\"" + archiveName + "\"";

            startInfo.Arguments += " -o" + "\"" + outputFolder + "\"";
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            int sevenZipExitCode = 0;
            using (Process sevenZip = Process.Start(startInfo))
```

Как сделать, что-бы процесс был виден в окне 7z? Т.е. чтобы при распаковке, открывалось окошко самого 7z (с прогресс-баром, временем и т.п.)

Comment: Да, именно его!

Comment: `startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` пишешь зачем тогда ты? копипастинг есть codemonkey путь =)

Comment: Просто не хотел долго ломать голову, а так спасибо)